# Send file chunks from Mediastream object with react-media-recorder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-s3, file-upload, safari

I am using react-media-recorder in my web application to allow the user to record video of himself, then I would like to send this file to my server (to upload it to AWS S3 with multipart upload). But in safari, there is a security mechanism so that it refreshes if it uses too much RAM, so I would like to send chunks of the video during the recording to the server. How can I do this if I receive a Mediastream object from the ReactMediaRecorder component?

Here is my code:

```
 <ReactMediaRecorder
      audio
      video
      askPermissionOnMount
      render={({
        status,
        startRecording,
        stopRecording,
        mediaBlobUrl,
        clearBlobUrl,
        previewStream,
        previewAudioStream,
      }) => (
        <div className={classes.cameraOnWrapper}>
          {status === "recording" || !mediaBlobUrl ? (
            <VideoPreview
             ...
            />
          ) : (
            <Playback
             ...
            />
          )}
        </div>
      )}
    />
```